# Undefined value in class method though it ís correctly set in constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following is a snippet from Node.js. No Babel installed, nor will my employer do so in case that was gonna be a suggestion :)

I simplified a class to see what the issue might be, but I'm totally stuck.
2 files, 1 class.

index.js

```
const SESSION = 'bla bla';
const VARS = 'abc';

const Helper = require('./helper');

const helpertest = new Helper(SESSION, VARS);
const x = Helper.setProduct();

console.log('End result :', x);
```

helper.js

```
module.exports = class Helper {

    constructor(SESSION, VARS) {
        this.SESSION = SESSION;
        this.VARS = VARS;
        console.log('Hi session', this.SESSION, this.VARS); // Hi session bla bla abc
    }

    static get SESSION() {
        return this.SESSION;
    }

    static setProduct() {

        console.log('Hi setProduct', SESSION); // Uncaught ReferenceError: SESSION is not defined

    }
}
```

The issue is passing the SESSION to this function

```
static setProduct() {
    
            console.log('Hi setProduct', SESSION); // Uncaught ReferenceError: SESSION is not defined
    
        }
```

I have tried:
this.SESSION, session, session() etc. etc.

No idea why it shows up correctly in the constructor and not in my method where i actually need it.

Please hand me some advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SESSION` is an instance variable, unavailable to a `static` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: Why are you using `static`?

Comment: The reason I use static is because there's actually another require() in the index.js which I need in the Helper file, when I do not use static, that one doesn't work. I try with the comments in this post and report back..

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `SESSION` is an instance member and cannot be accessed from a `static` context.

You could try not using `static` when defining `get SESSION()` and `setProduct`.

You call would then look like `helpertest.setProduct...` instead of `Helper.setProduct...`.

Comment: I'd still need this to include the class into index.js, no?
    const Helper = require('./helper');